# I don't get this relationship between heat, internal energy and heat capacity

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

Let me get started with the origin of my problem :

Ammonia (considered to be an ideal gas) is initially at $T_1 = 25   ^° C $ and $p_1 = 1 $ bar is heated
at constant pressure until the volume has tripled. The heat capacity behaves according to the
equation :
$C_p^{0} = \text{some polynomial} $.
Calculate the molar heat.

Now, the solution says : $$ q = \int_{T_1}^{T_2} \, C_p^{0} \, dT $$.

Here are my problems :

2. In our Script, Heat Capacity was defined as : $C_p = (\frac{\partial}{\partial T} U)_p $. So by integrating by $dT$, shouldn't you get : $ \Delta U = \int_{T_1}^{T_2} \, C_p \, dT  = \delta q + \delta W$

Comment: Your definition of Cp is incorrect.  It should read $C_p = (\frac{\partial}{\partial T} H)_p $

Comment: That would then make sense.